# Wordpress wp_editor won't add image

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code inside a plugin in a loop, so there are multiple WYSIWYG editors:

```
<?php wp_editor( stripslashes($arr['item-content']), $key.'-item-content', array(
    'editor_class' => 'tsort-contarea',
    'media_buttons' => true,
    'editor_height' => 360,

) ); ?>
```

When adding an image, the XHR request labelled `send-attachment-to-editor` inside `wp-includes/js/media-editor.js` has a `wp.media.view.settings.post.id` of 0. Also, `wp.media.view.settings.nonce.sendToEditor` is always this value: `e8b2eea867`

```
return wp.media.post( 'send-attachment-to-editor', {
                nonce:      wp.media.view.settings.nonce.sendToEditor,
                attachment: options,
                html:       html,
                post_id:    wp.media.view.settings.post.id
            });
```

The xhr request fires off fine, but doesn't add to any of the WYSIWYG. I'm sure that's because the post_id isn't set or because the nonce is not unique. What can I do to make this work? The Media Manager works absolutely fine on content pages.

Source file: http://pastebin.com/BhvqBLGB

Comment: Where are you doing this in the backend? Inside a custom metabox?

Comment: I'm modifying it inside a plugin but not a metabox. The plugin I'm using is http://codecanyon.net/item/content-timeline-responsive-wordpress-plugin/3027163 and here is the source file: http://pastebin.com/BhvqBLGB

Comment: This paste has been removed!

Comment: Can you clarify, the editor won't upload the image when you click Save/Update, does upload the image but doesn't attribute it to the post or save it in the post content, or it doesn't show the Upload Media buttons on the editor at all?

Comment: It shows up in the "Upload media" area absolutely fine, so the upload works ok. The problem arises when added to the content, it doesn't appear in the WYSIWYG. The image remains uploaded and can be inserted fine into a normal content page

Answer (score 7):

From [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor#Notes):

> Note that the ID that is passed to the wp_editor() function can only
>   be composed of lower-case letters. No underscores, no hyphens.
>   Anything else will cause the WYSIWYG editor to malfunction. (As of
>   3.6.1 you can use underscores in the ID.)

From what I see you are currently using a dash. Try changing that, and see how that works.

Comment: So I tried changing the code to this: 
`<?php
        $i++;
        wp_editor( stripslashes($arr['item-open-content']), $i.'itemopencontent', array(
         'editor_class' => 'tsortcontarea',
         'media_buttons' => true,
         'editor_height' => 360,
         'quicktags' => false

        ) ); ?>`
but to no avail.

Comment: @rickyduck - if you've got `i++` then that must mean you are prepending a number to itemopencontent - according to Manolis excerpt from the Codex that will also invalidate the id - lower case letters only?

Comment: Gah apologies, too early in the morning. What a pointless feature, ID must be unique so now I must do that by generating a random string, which is useless for post.

Comment: So I now have it prepending a random string (for example 'zyitemcontent'), still no help. Furthermore, sometimes the tinymce content turns blank and won't let me amend.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass me an updated source code to check?

Comment: @Manolis as the bounty expires in 1 hour, I'm attributing the 300 to you. I'd really appreciate it if you could continue to assist with this though, thanks

Comment: @rickyduck I will help more, just give me some time - currently busy with work

Comment: @Manolis have you had a chance to investigate this issue any further? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should check thoroughly for the `wp.media.view.settings.post.id` is 0 part, as I tried to reproduce the bug in `metabox` with multiple `editors` and I get post-id for the new post equal to non-zero (which is actually an `auto-draft` record in `wp_posts` table), image assignment is working properly for this case.

I believe there is something wrong with saving new post as `auto-draft` in your instance of WordPress (might be because of some plugin/theme)